# Unable to connect to the internet when using X11

Tags: networking, server, steam

I have a machine that is running Ubuntu server 22.04. When running the X server no applications can connect to the internet. I know it’s connected because I can install software from the console and the web server running on the machine is functional. I tried disabling ufw but that has had no effect. What is going wrong?

Before you ask. I’m using X to run steam to do game streaming

Comment: Is this a server provided by a third party hosting provider? Often they will firewall off common ports like this to prevent malicious software from downloading a payload. Worth checking with the provider. If it is a hosted server, the fact that apt works is likely because it's allowed via their own apt repositories (or mirrors).

Comment: it's hosted by me. The firewall is off on the machine so it should be able to work